# Roboto light and Roboto bold in a TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, spannablestring

Can I apply Roboto light and Roboto bold in same TextView on Android 2.3 like that?

```
**user** has been publish a beez
```

Where `**user**` is Roboto bold and `has been publish a beez` is Roboto light

Comment: You have to download the [ROBOTO font](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html) in your assets/fonts folder, first. Then access that font as described in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6746775/2649012). And finally put it together with Lokesh's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do ..

```
String firstWord = "user";
String secondWord = "has been publish a beez";

// Create a new spannable with the two strings
Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(firstWord+secondWord);

// Set the custom typeface to span over a section of the spannable object
spannable.setSpan( new CustomTypefaceSpan("sans-serif",CUSTOM_TYPEFACE), 0, firstWord.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spannable.setSpan( new CustomTypefaceSpan("sans-serif-light",SECOND_CUSTOM_TYPEFACE), firstWord.length(), firstWord.length() + secondWord.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// Set the text of a textView with the spannable object
textView.setText( spannable );
```

You can use Roboto natively from Android 4.1+ like this:

```
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"           // roboto regular
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"     // roboto light
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
```

Comment: CustomTypefaceSpan is not defined.

Comment: @coolcool1994 use `TypefaceSpan`, ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/text/style/TypefaceSpan