# how to set Android Typeface from xml

Tags: android, android-typeface

```
Typeface fontRobo = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf");
viewTotalValue.setText(total.toString());
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing a font under assets folder from XML file in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746665/accessing-a-font-under-assets-folder-from-xml-file-in-android)

Comment: If you dont want to do this to every TextView you can create class that extends TextView and set your Typeface in there. Then you can use that class in your xml files like **com.your.customview.package.CustomFontTextView**.

Answer (score 19):

You could create your own TextView by overriding the TextView like this:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setType(context);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setType(context);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setType(context);
    }

    private void setType(Context context){
        this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "foo.ttf"));

        this.setShadowLayer(1.5f, 5, 5, getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.black_shadow));
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<com.your.project.package.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/oppinfo_mtv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"  
        android:text="Player 1"
        />
```

Comment: Show an example to him how to use it in xml file too :)

Comment: You were TOO fast! Nice answer

Answer (score 3):

You could create a custom class that extends `TextView`, let's say `FontTextView`.

Define a special string attribute for that class, let's say "font".

Then, in your `FontTextView` constructor based on the value of the `font` attribute, choose the appropriate `Typeface` from your assets.

See:

- [Creating a View Class Google Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)
- [Defining custom attributes SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/defining-custom-attrs/3441986#3441986)

Answer (score 3):

Extending TextView just for setting font looks so expensive and not good.
The most clear way is to use [Android Data-Binding Framework](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) and BindingAdapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("bind:font")
public static void setTypeface(TextView textView, int index) {
    Typeface myTypeface = //retrieve typeface from cache, based on some font index
    textView.setTypeface(myTypeface);
}
```

declaration in xml:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:font="@{R.attr.Proxima_Nova_Regular}" 
/>
```

attrs.xml:

```
<attr name="Proxima_Nova_Regular"/>
<attr name="Proxima_Nova_Black"/>    
<attr name="Proxima_Nova_Bold"/>
```

or use resources integers same way

In your cache/creator helper determine dependencies between R.attr.*Your Font* and instance of typeface.