# Custom style for custom font on Android

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I'm able to load my custom font in Android this way:

```
mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/AvenirNextCondensed.ttc");
```

I'm loading it fine, the issue i'm facing is that I need `Medium` style, which doesn't exist. My font always defaults to bold regardless. Is there a way to set the custom font style for a custom font? I have been digging into this for some time, and saw the below links:

[Add custom font for complete android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926263/add-custom-font-for-complete-android-application)

[Accessing a font under assets folder from XML file in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746665/accessing-a-font-under-assets-folder-from-xml-file-in-android)

Comment: is it .ttf or .ttc and is this font file bold?

Comment: post your xml where you use the typeFace

Comment: I created my own `TextView` implementation where I am getting the `TypeFace` using the above code and setting the typeface that way.

Comment: The xml simply uses it in that fashion.

Comment: it's a `ttc`. This font file has bold, medium, etc.

Comment: that will always happen as you are setting the typeface AvenirNextCondensed.ttf look for other ttf files like AvenirNextRegular.ttf and use it for medium